# Blazor Hybrid error on release version in IOS

Tags: blazor, maui, apexcharts, blazor-hybrid

I have a blazor hybrid application that uses Blazor-ApexChart to generate some basic charts. It works fine in the IOS simulator and also with a connected IPhone if i use debug configuration. However if i produce a release version ( even a local release sent to the iphone ) the app crashes without showing any specific error.

Any ideas of what may be happening? it is not something related to data because i tried with a very simple chart and static data and it is the same behavior.

Comment: What do the logs show?  Do you have any crash reporting tools installed?

Comment: I can't see any error, i connected the console application and i don't see the crash, in fact it does not crash. It displays the generic error message of blazor. ( the yellow one ). I tried to isolate the error using an <ErrorBoundary> section and it crashed from the beggining . I changed to radzen blazor and the same behavior. So my question now is.. is there any one using a chart component on ios with blazor hybrid?

Comment: Functionality that works in debug but not in release is often a linking problem. In Xamarin, I would temporarily change Release Build's Linking to "None" to see if the problem goes away. If it does, then you know its a linking problem. (But don't publish that way - app would be large.) Then it took some trial-and-error to find out what was getting removed by linker, so you can add an explicit reference to keep it around. Sorry, I don't know how to do that Linking test and customization in Maui iOS.